# How can I use a column as indicator?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have a big dataset with values for left and right hand movement.
I created it like this:

```py
data_low = {'left':fourier_transform_left,'right':fourier_transform_right}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_low)
```

The resulting df looks like this:

```py
       left     right
0 -0.074656 -0.071354
1 -0.096238 -0.142640
2 -0.097521 -0.111667
3 -0.064493 -0.036810
4 -0.095617  0.025975
```

In order to plot it, I want to use the columns left/right as hues, so it looks like this:

```py
   values   movement
0 -0.074656 left 
1 -0.071354 right 
2 -0.096238 left
3 -0.142640 right
```

...and so on. Does someone know how to achieve this? I tried to transpose the dataset but that doesn't work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = df.stack().droplevel(0).reset_index()
x.columns = ["movement", "values"]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
  movement    values
0     left -0.074656
1    right -0.071354
2     left -0.096238
3    right -0.142640
4     left -0.097521
5    right -0.111667
6     left -0.064493
7    right -0.036810
8     left -0.095617
9    right  0.025975
```